# Lazy load handling (Hibernate + Spring MVC)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

What is the best solution to handle lazy loaded objects in a Spring MVC application? I have already made some searches about this topic and I have found following solutions:

**Open session in view:** open a session for each request and close it after view rendering. The problem with this solution is that I need to lazy load objects also outside of Spring MVC model (Junit test case for example). Another discussed problem about this solution is exception handling. What if a transaction throws an exception during the view rendering?

**Open session explicitely:** open a session explicitely whenever a I need to lazy load an object. Actually this solution should work but I don't think It's the right way.

**Using AOP:** create an aspect that wrap a lazy load method in a session. This could be a solution but I don't know at what level of my application I should define poitcuts

**Create custom queries:** create queries for lazy load and queries for eager load. This solution actually works but It seems to me a wrong application of lazy load pattern

Comment: check this post on OSIV pros/cons http://blog.jhades.org/open-session-in-view-pattern-pros-and-cons/

Comment: The problem with using custom queries is that they force the join onto the related object, which is not always the most optimal solution.  Sometimes its more efficient to have 1 query for main object and N separate queries for related objects.

Comment: Also, its nice to separate the query from the lazy loading, as it means you can have a single method for lazy loading (eg: loadRelationsRequiredByDefault() ), which can be reused by many different queries returning the same object (or list of objects).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no solution that is always better in all cases, the problem is that `@Transactional` on the service layer will not keep the session open when the rendering phase starts.

The session is flushed, the transaction commited and the session closed before the rendering starts.

One way to solve this is to use custom queries that load the data that is needed at each moment depending on the view that is being built.

Another way is to use open session in view, which keeps the session opened at rendering time, but it might give rise to N+1 problems in the application due to unintended use of lazy loading.

Also open session in view might cause problems with non repeatable reads, where some data was read by the service layer and used to commit a transaction, but when the view rendering starts that data is no longer available or was modified, and it was important for building the view.

See this [post](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessionInView) from the JBoss Seam team on the use of OSIV goes through these issues ([Seam](http://seamframework.org/) was developed my many of the same developers as Hibernate).

The different approaches have different pros and cons, depending on what the project priorities are. If the convenience of not having to write custom queries is significative as there many queries to write, then OSIV is a good choice. Ocasional N+1 problems can be tackled case by case and lived with.

If the emphasis is on keeping the queries under control because the application is for example performance critical then custom queries are an option.

There is really no clear cut best solution. If you use a view technology that runs on client side (something like angular.js) instead of the server then you don't run into these kind of issues because there is no server side rendering involved.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not shure if it fit's your requirements and not if it is "the" correct way to handle it but I make use of the @Transactional Annotation. So I would have:

```
@Autowired
AccountDAO accountDAO; 

@Transactional
public List<String> getNamesOfAccount(String accountName){
    Account account = accountDAO.get(accountName);
    return account.getNames();
}
```

the names attribute in Account is lazy, and is loaded just before the return. 
If there is a better way let be hear!

Comment: This could be a solution. I don't know if it is the best way. I'll wait for others suggestions.

Comment: What is nice about that solution is, that you only have the EntityManager / SessionFactory in your DAO. If you do not call getNames() nothing is loaded. If you do than Spring does everything for you and you do not have to open a Session or something.

Comment: What doesn't convince me is that I cannot acces "lazy fields" through domain objects interface but only through DAO.

Comment: Why? account is a domain object in my case. And one time it needs to be loaded. The access of the lazy field "names" is without the dao

Comment: If you load an Account instance you cannot access the field "names" outside the transaction boudaries without calling before "getNamesOfAccount" otherwise you have a LazyInitializationException